# Looking for help on joining query

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, inner-join

im taking my very first programming (sql) class. I've got no tech background whatsoever and I'm having a little trouble getting the code down.
here is the what the database looks like.

#### BOOK

```
  BOOK_CODE (UNIQUE)
  BOOKTITLE
  PUBLISHER_CODE
  BOOKTYPE
  PRICE
```

#### INVENTORY

```
 BOOK_CODE (UNIQUE)
 BRANCH_NUM (UNIQUE)
 ON_HAND
```

The question is, list the books (titles) that are available in branches 3 and 4 (on both at the same time).

Im thinking i need to use the following tables: booktitle on the book table , bookcode on both tables ( book and inventory), and branch_num on inventory table.

also the answer can only show the book titles available on branches 3 and 4 (at the same time) and no other columns.

sorry if im making no sense. like i said im a n00b.

Comment: Just to make sure, when you say "...show the book titles available on branches 3 and 4...", do you mean that the `ON_HAND` field must be greater than 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT BOOKTITLE FROM BOOK
WHERE BOOK_CODE IN (SELECT BOOK_CODE FROM INVENTORY WHERE BRANCH_NUM = 3 AND ON_HAND > 0)
    AND BOOK_CODE IN (SELECT BOOK_CODE FROM INVENTORY WHERE BRANCH_NUM = 4 AND ON_HAND > 0);
```

OR

```
SELECT BOOKTITLE FROM
(
    SELECT BOOK.BOOK_CODE, BOOKTITLE, COUNT(*) AS BRANCH_COUNT FROM BOOK
    INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON BOOK.BOOK_CODE = INVENTORY.BOOK_CODE
        AND INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM IN (3, 4)
    GROUP BY BOOK.BOOK_CODE, BOOKTITLE
) B
WHERE B.BRANCH_COUNT = 2;
```

Comment: first one is dead on, the professor wanted us to use subqueries but i didnt know exactly how/where. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
 select distinct BOOKTITLE from BOOK a, INVENTORY b
      where a.BOOK_CODE = b.BOOK_CODE and a.BOOK_CODE in 
    (select distinct p.BOOK_CODE from Inventory p, Inventory q where p.BOOK_CODE = 
    q.BOOK_CODE 
    and p.BRANCH_NUM = 3 AND q.BRANCH_NUM = 4);
```

Comment: You need to prefix BOOKTITLE with `a`.

Comment: This will give you all books that are in branches 3 OR 4. Not necessarily both.

Comment: ah! Didn't notice he needed it to be in both.  I'll amend it.

Comment: this is what i was doing but it was giving me the wrong answer , i think i figured out why. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
SELECT  BK.BOOKTITLE
FROM    BOOK BK
INNER JOIN INVENTORY INV1
ON INV1.BOOK_CODE = BK.BOOK_CODE
INNER JOIN INVENTORY INV2
ON INV2.BOOK_CODE = BK.BOOK_CODE
WHERE   INV1.BRANCH_NUM = 3
AND INV2.BRANCH_NUM = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question tells you the fields you need from the table, which gives you this as a starting point:

```
SELECT booktitle FROM book . . .
```

That alone will give you a list of every `booktitle` in the table `book`, but you want to filter it down to only those books in both `branch_num` 3 and 4.

When you `JOIN` two or more tables, you're looking to match rows based on some shared valued; `book_code`, in this case.

Since you want to see only those books in both tables, you'll want to use an `INNER JOIN`.  (I'm assuming ON_HAND is an INT describing the number of copies in the branch.)

```
SELECT booktitle FROM book
INNER JOIN inventory USING (book_code)
WHERE inventory.onhand > 0
```

That query will return a list of every book that is available in any branch.  Modifying the query, you can restrict it only to those books in `branch_num` 3:

```
SELECT booktitle FROM book
INNER JOIN inventory USING (book_code)
WHERE inventory.onhand > 0 AND inventory.branch_num = 3
```

...but you need books in both branches 3 and 4, so you'll need to do another join on the `inventory` table.  But how can you distinguish the two?  Use table aliases:

```
SELECT booktitle FROM book
INNER JOIN inventory AS inventory1 USING (book_code)
INNER JOIN inventory AS inventory2 USING (book_code)
WHERE inventory1.onhand > 0 AND inventory1.branch_num = 3 AND inventory2.onhand > 0 AND inventory2.branch_num = 4
```

That should give you what you're looking for.

For a much better explanation of joins, see [MySQL Joins](http://mysqljoin.com/) and [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

[Note: this problem could also be using subqueries, which you should try to do.]